# Regex for creating proper php array structure from text

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a problem with proper regex expression for my case. So i have this "text" which i need to convert in to the PHP array with find an replace function in my code editor

```
$grid['added'][0][qwer'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][0][tzui'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][1][sdfg'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][2][ghjk'] = 'asda';
....
$grid['added'][4][nbmh'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][666][fghz'] = 'asda';
```

desired output

```
$grid['added'][0]['qwer'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][0]['tzui'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][1]['sdfg'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][2]['ghjk'] = 'asda';
....
$grid['added'][4]['nbmh'] = 'asda';
$grid['added'][666]['fghz'] = 'asda';
```

So far i'm trying to fetch all numbers inside square brackets, then add that apostrophe but editor doesn't find any thing for the following regex.

```
/\[[0-9]+\]/
```

So how should my regex look like so i can add that apostrophe to my "text" in order to have proper array structure for my code. If you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Comment: Please share the code or at least let us know how you are using the regex.

Comment: Is your original text also missing the left apostrophe on the last key?

Comment: whell original text looked like this grid[added][0][qwer]:asda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
\['?([a-zA-Z]+)'?\]
```

Replace:

```
['$1']
```

This finds any set of letters within square brackets, that may or may not have any quotes around it, and makes sure there are two quotes.

Comment: And please up vote question, because  i got - without any explanation :/

Comment: @Valor_, I agree that your question was understandable and didn't deserve a downvote.  So I upvoted to compensate.